# No signal on LAN network plug

Tags: networking

I tried to reconfigure my network setup. My vodafone router is connected to a TV/DSL cable near the fuse box of my appartment. From there I can connect the 4 LAN ports of my router to the respective 4 LAN plugs which are supposed to be connected to the plugs in the individual rooms in my appartment.

However all plugs in my appartment remain dead, no matter what I do. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

do I need cross-over cables instead of patch cables?
could it be that my router is too weak for longer connections (25 m - 50 m cable, inside the walls so this is just a rough estimate)
how could I test if the connections to the indivdual rooms are working? Do I need a special testing device for that?
my appartment is brand new (4 years old) I cannot believe that all 4 plugs should be dead / wrongly installed ...

**Update**
Meanwhile I bought a RJ45 cable tester as mentioned in the comments. Indeed the numbers displayed on the device tester differ on both ends of each cable. Basically

- at the beginning of each cable (at the fuse station) I see "1,2,3,6"
- and at the end of the cable either "1,2,7,8" or in some cases / cables "3,4,5,6"

I guess that means something is wrong. I also opened one of the LAN plugs. Here a picture:
[image]
Does anyone know whether I can switch some cables around to fix that?
Colors look all correct to me...

Some more infos:

- the second green cable is a "TV cable"

Here is a picture with a front view of the whole plug along with a picture of the testing device
[image]

**Update 2**
It seems like **ONLY** the y-cabel from "[homeway](https://www.amazon.de/y-kabel4-lan-tae-0m-ST/dp/B01A8DFS3W/ref=piup_2/262-7362090-8663913?pd_rd_w=znGzT&pf_rd_p=9100c938-e10e-4e51-99a6-d5cd5f23c53f&pf_rd_r=12126ADH8MPBBR8BYYNQ&pd_rd_r=523689ab-4b57-4671-980b-dee3843fa88d&pd_rd_wg=gfEA8&pd_rd_i=B01A8DFS3W&psc=1)" does work in establishing a connection. I even tried a completely new patch cable to no avail...

Comment: Have you used these plugs anytime in the last four years?

Comment: No, I just moved into the appartment half a year ago

Comment: Easiest thing would be to get a RJ45 cable tester. It could be that the panels are either not wired at all, or wrong, or with not all of the 8 wires connected. You can get them for under 10 bucks

Comment: First of all, could you also provide images of your fusebox? If there is a patchpanel, please show the connections. If the wires simply end in plugs, please make a photo where we can se the order of the wires inside the plug. Second, could you add which tester you've bought? Otherwise it is hard to interpret the readings. For anything faster than 10MBit/s all eight wires need to be connected. It could be that some of the white wires are not correctly connected, as they got no apparent markings at all.

Comment: It could also be that there is some nasty junction somewhere, but this is highly unlikely, as the apartment is relatively new

Comment: Re photo – if this is just one plug, why does it look like there are two cables going to it? (One of them _looks_ like it's some kind of ground wire, but it also looks nearly identical to the other one which I assume is Ethernet.)

Comment: From the LED description it does sound like bad wiring. Now 3-6 is indeed a pair in Ethernet, but it should go to 3-6 on the other end too, definitely not 7-8... (it's like they tried to use "crossover" writing for no reason _and_ wired it upside down, too?) And the 3,4,5,6 just makes no sense at all for Ethernet – was that port wired for analog telephone? Finally, even if you swap them around, having two good pairs would still limit you to 100 Mbps (10 MB/s), no Gigabit (you need all four pairs for that).

Comment: Re last photo – why does it look like there are two cables coming out of the red plug?

Answer (score 0):

I meanwhile found out that the problem lies with the lan cable that "feeds the signal into the plug". It turns out that "normal lan cables" do not work for the connection between router and the cable that goes inside the wall. If I use a cable called "homeway > LAN" the connection ist working fine.

the cables I tested before work for "the final meter" - i.e. connection from the end-plug to the computer. but the "first meter" where the signal is fed into the plug is apparantly a proprietary format.

I even got an [answer](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Homeway-HW-Y-Cable-LAN-TAE-HCAHNG-B2404-A010/dp/B01A8DFS3W/ref=pd_sbs_1/261-6494569-2649803?pd_rd_w=048AC&pf_rd_p=7cf49d79-ae26-401a-94b7-1dec7a725ba4&pf_rd_r=XDY1TK228Z20Y55424QH&pd_rd_r=78eea037-e479-40db-92c6-df5926a69b45&pd_rd_wg=1th93&pd_rd_i=B01A8DFS3W&psc=1) from the company "homeway" on amazon confirming that:

"This is a bespoke connector for Homeway systems. It allows carrying phone and data signals on a single cable. On one side you connect your home router and analogue phone termination. The red RJ45 goes on your home patch panel. At the wall socket at the other end the signal is split in data and voice again and you can connect your computer and your analogue phone"

Comment: Normal cables work with all normal devices. There are no "proprietary formats" in Ethernet, only "incorrectly wired" ones.